# JSON typeMismatch

Tags: android, json, arrays

Am trying to parse the data from JSON the But I am getting an error saying JSONType mismatch,

The code I am using to parse the data is as follow

```
    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlString);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("product");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put(AppConstants.SUB_CATEGORY_HREF, jsonobject.getString(AppConstants.SUB_CATEGORY_HREF))   ;
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

the json array structure is as follows

```
              {
"success": true,
"product": {
    "id": "42",
    "name": "product name",
    "description": "<p>Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here.</p>  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> ",
    "image": "http://test.com/image/cache/data/products/eyes-600x600.png",
    "image1": "http://test.com/image/cache/data/products/product2-600x600.png",
    "image2": "http://test.com/image/cache/data/products/lips-600x600.png",
    "image3": "http://test.com/image/cache/data/products/product6-600x600.png",
    "image4": null,
    "price": "100KD",
    "special": "70KD",
    "related products": [
        {
            "product_id": "30",
            "thumb": "http://image/cache/data/products/product6-600x600.png",

        },
        {
            "product_id": "35",
            "thumb": "http://image/cache/data/products/eyes-600x600.png",

        }
    ]
}
}
```

The detailed logcat output is giving

```
06-18 15:17:02.834: W/System.err(8183):     atorg.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
06-18 15:17:02.834: W/System.err(8183):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:553)
06-18 15:17:02.834: W/System.err(8183):     at com.dairam.fragments.ProductDetailsFragment$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(ProductDetailsFragment.java:82)
06-18 15:17:02.834: W/System.err(8183):     at com.dairam.fragments.ProductDetailsFragment$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(ProductDetailsFragment.java:1)
06-18 15:17:02.834: W/System.err(8183):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-18 15:17:02.844: W/System.err(8183):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-18 15:17:02.844: W/System.err(8183):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-18 15:17:02.854: W/System.err(8183):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-18 15:17:02.854: W/System.err(8183):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-18 15:17:02.854: W/System.err(8183):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("product"); product is not json array ,it is json object

Comment: check ur jsonarray.. `product` is the one of the array object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the line:

```
jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("product");
```

Is trying to retrieve an array called product, which doesn't exist. product is an object.
You can mitigate the error, by doing:

```
jsonObject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("product");
```

This assumes that you have changed the type of your variable. But then you can access other parts of the object with `jsonObject.get()`;

Answer (score 1):

with below line of code your looking for json array

```
jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("product");
```

in below is json its json object. so the error is type missmatch.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "product": {
"id": "42",
"name": "product name",
"description": "<p>Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here.</p>  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here. Your product description will be here.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> ",
"image": "http://test.com/image/cache/data/products/eyes-600x600.png",
"image1": "http://test.com/image/cache/data/products/product2-600x600.png",
"image2": "http://test.com/image/cache/data/products/lips-600x600.png",
"image3": "http://test.com/image/cache/data/products/product6-600x600.png",
"image4": null,
"price": "100KD",
"special": "70KD",
"related products": [
    {
        "product_id": "30",
        "thumb": "http://image/cache/data/products/product6-600x600.png",

    },
    {
        "product_id": "35",
        "thumb": "http://image/cache/data/products/eyes-600x600.png",

    }
]
}
}
```

json array starts with `[` and ends with `]`

for example `related products` is json array

```
"related products": [
    {
        "product_id": "30",
        "thumb": "http://image/cache/data/products/product6-600x600.png",

    },
    {
        "product_id": "35",
        "thumb": "http://image/cache/data/products/eyes-600x600.png",

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this problem creates when you get json data which is array or object type. If it doesn't match you would get this type of error. Please use:

- For jsonarray data

  ```
  jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("product");
  ```
- For jsonObject data

  ```
  jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONObject("product");
  ```